# Implement missing platform for MvvmCross plugin

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, xamarin, mvvmcross

I want to use an MvvmCross plugin in my project, however one of my platforms is Wpf.
Unfortunately there's no Wpf implementation (https://github.com/brianchance/MvvmCross-UserInteraction).

What is the proper way of adding WPF platform implementation to my project?

More specifically, my questions are:

- In the implementation I need to use UI controls and components to display message boxes, thus should it be "WPF Custom Control Library" or can I use just standard "Class library"?
- Do I have to add Nuget packages Mvvm.CrossCore and Mvvm UserInteractionPlugin to my WPF implementation library?

Ideally I'd like to create and test WPF implementation in my own project and then contribute it to plugin repo on github.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest would be to clone the original repo. Then add a new Class Library project for your WPF implementation.

If you look at the existing Windows Store project, it simply adds a project reference to the UserInteraction (PCL) project.

Create a *UserInteraction* class that implements *IUserInteraction*. Add your WPF implementation there.

Include the *Plugin* class so it will auto-register in MvvmCross.

You can then modify the existing .nuspec file to add entries for your WPF assemblies.

This is pretty much how all MvvmCross plugins work.

Comment: I actually ended up creating my own library that references MvvmCross Core and UserInteraction nuget libraries. Just created a Plugin class and IUserInteraction implementation. It works nicely.

Comment: I don't like the idea of forking very much in this case. It's much better for me to have a dependency as a Nuget package rather than a whole bunch of code in my solution.

Comment: That's fine too. But like I said, you could have created a NuGet package and referenced that in your project. You don't have to include the entire solution in your project. Bonus is that once you verify it works properly, you could have sent a pull request to get your WPF version included.

Comment: I hope I'll be able to do that when I polish the plugin. Actually I found that this UserInteraction plugin kinda lacks customization freedom, all platform implementations work only with standard message boxes. I think it should allow using custom forms/controls for alerts. This is a challenging task, but doable I think :) So there's a plenty of room for contribution.